# How to use for loop to reference previously assigned variables

Tags: excel, vba

Working on creating a text file from an excel worksheet with the following.  I've assigned variables to Set1, Set2, etc. and am trying to reference them but the `fileStream.WriteLine` is not putting the correct values in.  It seems like this should be extremely easy but I cannot get it to work.

```
Sub CreateTextFile()

Dim filePath As String

filePath = CStr(Sheet1.Range("D2").Value & "TextFile.txt")

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim fileStream As TextStream

Set1 = "a"
Set2 = "b"
Set3 = "c"
Set4 = "d"
Set5 = "e"
Set6 = "f"
Set7 = "g""
Set8 = "h"
Set9 = "i"
Set10 = "j"
Set11 = "k"

Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)

For G = 1 To 11 '123

fileStream.WriteLine SetG
fileStream.WriteLine ""

Next G

fileStream.Close

'If fso.FileExists(filePath) Then
'    MsgBox "Text file created in quote folder"
'End If

End Sub
```

Looking for an outlet like follows:

```
a

b

c

etc.
```

Comment: Use an [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-arrays)

Comment: You can't refer to variables with an index like that.  You'll need an alternative data structure. Depending on your actual requirements you could use an Array, a Dictionary,  or a User Defined Class

Comment: Thank you both, currently trying to rewrite this with an array.  I've actually never used one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.  I've corrected this using an array with the code below.

```
Sub CreateTextFile()

Dim filePath As String

filePath = CStr(Sheet1.Range("D2").Value & "TextFile.txt")

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim fileStream As TextStream

Dim DataSet(10) As String

DataSet(0) = "a"
DataSet(1) = "b"
DataSet(2) = "c"
DataSet(3) = "d"
DataSet(4) = "e"
DataSet(5) = "f"
DataSet(6) = "g"
DataSet(7) = "h"
DataSet(8) = "i"
DataSet(9) = "j"
DataSet(10) = "k"

Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)

Dim item As Variant

For Each item In DataSet

fileStream.WriteLine item
fileStream.WriteLine ""

Next item

fileStream.Close

If fso.FileExists(filePath) Then
MsgBox "Text file created in quote folder"
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you for the help and if you see anywhere else that could be improved please let me know.